# Avoid halting while JXL calling WritableWorkbook.close()

Tags: java, resources, jxl

We found that when generating xls using JXL, calling WritableWorkbook.close() will halting the system. Seems that resources are not released.

[Someone has also encountered this problem but no answer was given](http://www.javaproblemstips.com/article.action?aid=449009&cur=2)

we tested several versions of JXL, but nothing changed. where's the problem?

```
book.write();
//close() caused halting
book.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

After investigating the source code, we found that when calling WritableWorkbook.close(), the default behavior calls System.gc() every time!

```
void close(boolean cs) throws IOException, JxlWriteException {
    CompoundFile cf = new CompoundFile(data, 
                                   data.getPosition(), 
                                   outputStream, 
                                   readCompoundFile);
    cf.write();

    outputStream.flush();
    data.close();

    if (cs) {
      outputStream.close();
    }

    // Cleanup the memory a bit
    data = null;

    if (!workbookSettings.getGCDisabled()) {
      System.gc();
    }
}
```

There are two ways to avoid this via system property

- `jxl.nogc=true` , disable gc of JXL(add `-Djxl.nogc=true` to jvm parameter)
- `XX:+DisableExplicitGC` , disable all explicit GC(which is desirable under most circumstances).

Answer (score 0):

```
WorkbookSettings workbookSettings = new WorkbookSettings();
        workbookSettings.setGCDisabled(true);
        readwb = Workbook.getWorkbook(file.getInputStream(), workbookSettings);
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what this code is doing? While it may (or may not) solve the problem, at the moment it doesn't show how or why.